# How can I pass a list of different query params to a request body respectively?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have a list of  query params that I want to pass to a function as a parameter. This function calls an api, so each item in this list of params get passed respectively for each call and fetches the results associated with this param till it hits the end of this list.

Here is the params list(each item in this list has a different range of dates that has a different set of results):

```
REQUEST_PARAMS = [
    {
        "period": "range",
        "date": "2020-10-08,2020-10-31",
        "format": "JSON",
        "module": "API",
        "method": "**",
        "flat": "1",
        "filter_limit": "-1",
    },
    {
        "period": "range",
        "date": "2020-11-01,2020-11-30",
        "format": "JSON",
        "module": "API",
        "method": "**",
        "flat": "1",
        "filter_limit": "-1",
    },
    {
        "period": "range",
        "date": "2020-12-01,2020-12-31",
        "format": "JSON",
        "module": "API",
        "method": "**",
        "flat": "1",
        "filter_limit": "-1",
    }
]
```

Here is the function that makes the call to the targeted api:

```
 def get_the_results(max_retries=4):
        """
        Fetch the response object from the api
        :param max_retries: The max number of retries in case of error.
        :return: list of dictionaries for the results
        """
        return fetch_and_validate_response(URL, REQUEST_PARAMS, max_retries)


def fetch_and_validate_response(url, params, max_retries=0):
"""
Fetch a response object from provided URL.
:param url: The url for the request
:param params: The parameters for the request
:param max_retries: The max number of retries in case of error.
:return: json object if successful, None if retries due to network error continues to fail
"""
try:
    response = get(url=url, params=params, verify=False)
    response.raise_for_status()
    response_decoded = response.json()
    # Raise a RequestException if the API returns a result with an error.
    try:
        if response_decoded.get('result') == 'error':
            log.info(f"Error in response: {response_decoded.get('result')} - {response_decoded.get('message')}")
            raise RequestException
    except AttributeError:
        log.info("No error detected in response object.")

    return response_decoded
except HTTPError as e:
    log.exception(f'Network Error: HTTP error {response.status_code} occurred while getting query: {url}: {e}')
except ConnectionError as e:
    log.exception(f'Network Error: A connection error occurred while getting query: {url} with {params}: {e}')
except Timeout as e:
    log.exception(f'Network Error: The request timed out for query: {url} with {params}: {e}')
except RequestException as e:
    log.exception(f'Network Error: An error occurred while getting {url}. Please double-check the url: {e}')

if max_retries <= 0:
    return None

time.sleep(5)

return fetch_and_validate_response(url, params, max_retries - 1)
```

I want to print the results that fetched from this call in this function:

```
def construct_results_dict():
    data = get_the_results()
    for item in data:
        print(item)
```

your help is so much appreciated  - Thanks :)

Comment: Loop over the ```REQUEST_PARAMS``` and pass them to your function.

Comment: @Ram I tried this solution, it only picks the first item and return its own result then the call ended!

Comment: That's happening because you are using ```return``` in your function and so the function stops after the first call. Could you post your complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

Iterate over the `REQUEST_PARAMS` list and call `fetch_and_validate_response()` with each parameter and then store the return values of `fetch_and_validate_response()` in a list and return that list.

```
def get_the_results(max_retries=4):
        """
        Fetch the response object from the api
        :param max_retries: The max number of retries in case of error.
        :return: list of dictionaries for the results
        """
        # results list to store the results returned by the below function
        results = []
        for param in REQUEST_PARAMS:
            results.append(fetch_and_validate_response(URL, param, max_retries)) 
        
        # Finally return the results list
        return results
```

And Now, the `results` list will be returned to `data` in the below function.

```
def construct_results_dict():
    data = get_the_results()
    for item in data:
        print(item)
```